# Putting a group together around a circular table

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, symmetry

> A group of ten students includes triplets Alex, Alison and Alice
> wearing black, white and yellow t-shirts respectively. They are to be
> seated in groups of five around two tables: one green and one red. The
> triplets insist on sitting together. Determine the number of seating
> arrangements possible.

**Choosing the groups** The group with the triplets need two additional people to be chosen in:
$${10-3 \choose 2} ={7 \choose 2}=21 \text{ Ways}$$

**Seating the non-triplet group** Five people can sit around a circular table in
$$(5-1)!=4!=24 \text{ Ways}$$

**Seating the triplets** Since the triplets must sit together, consider them as one person:
$$5-2=3 \text{ people}\implies (3-1)!=2!=2 \text { circular arrangements}$$
The triplets are distinguishable and can be arranged among themselves in $3!=6 \text{ ways}$. The total number of ways of seating the triplets, by the multiplication principle is:
$$2\times 6=12$$

**Choosing the table**
We have the following two choices:
{Green: Triplet, Red: Non-triplet}
{Red: Triplet, Green: Non-triplet}
$$2 \text{ ways}$$

**Final Answer** The final answer is then:
$$21\times 24 \times 12 \times2 =12,096$$

Is this correct?

Comment: When posting a "contest math" question, it's important to identify the contest so we can confirm we're not providing the answers to a live contest.

Comment: This is just a question I thought of. It is not from any live contest.

Comment: Seems correct but the last multiplication is 12096